# Column sorting to include entire content in display table

Tags: html, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable, display

I am using `sortable="true"` for column level sorting of display table with pagination, but when I click on header it is sorting only the current page contents. When I go to the next page the content remains as before without any sorting. Is there a way to sort the entire content of display table when column header is clicked? Below is the code to display my display table.

```
<display:table class="displayTable" id="person" name="persons" requestURI="personDetails" export="true" pagesize="10" requestURIcontext="false">
    <display:column style="width: 30%; border: 1px solid #000;" title="Date" sortable="true">
            <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" value="${person.reportDate}" />
    </display:column>
    <display:column style="width: 30%; border: 1px solid #000;" property="personName" title="Name" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column style="width: 30%; border: 1px solid #000;" property="personAge" title="Age" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. Add sort="list" attribute in display:table tag to include the entire list in sorting, if not only current page which is displayed will be sorted.

```
<display:table sort="list" class="displayTable" id="person" name="persons" requestURI="personDetails" export="true" pagesize="10" requestURIcontext="false" >
    <display:column style="width: 30%; border: 1px solid #000;" title="Date" sortable="true">
            <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" value="${person.reportDate}" />
    </display:column>
    <display:column style="width: 30%; border: 1px solid #000;" property="personName" title="Name" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column style="width: 30%; border: 1px solid #000;" property="personAge" title="Age" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
```